Weirdest behaviour (pycharm, python, virtual environment, loading error)
Long story short: python "sees" some files but not others.


And this is what I'm trying to do:
I want to use "enchant" spellchecking lib in python. I've written some code that works perfectly in external terminal (= linux terminal = system shell), but fails when I run under pycharm. The error message is "ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found and maybe needs to be installed."
These are other infos somehow related to the problem:

I'm on Linux Pop OS
the project has a virtual environment set up (python 3.11, and system is 3.10.12)
the installed pyenchant in the venv is 3.2.2, I've also forced to 3.0.0 as seen somewhere, nothing improves
I've tried "sudo systemctl stop apparmor" but it doesn't change anything. When apparmor is active it doesn't show any new entry when the code fails
The code was giving that error on the system terminal, then I installed "python3-enchant" from deb package manager and it started working, but only in the terminal, not in pycharm
pycharm is installed via flatpak
I've overwritten the files in the venv pip package (pyenchant) with the contents from the deb package, with no luck. then I've restored the original ones
I've tried adding global variables to pycharm runtime configuration. If I run the script without global variables I get the "ImportError", but if I add "PYENCHANT_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libenchant-2.so.2" to runtime configuration, I get "OSError: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", that means, thinks the file doesn't exist, as shown in the screenshots.

In short, I don't think it's a problem specific from the pyenchant library. I just find VERY weird that the simplest os.path.exists fails to detect the presence of some files, but detects others. They all are in the same folder and have similar attributes (readable permissions). I can't understand what is happening.

What do you mean by "external terminal"?  Do you just mean "external to PyCharm?  You don't have some remote system involved here?

What does lexists return?

@TimRoberts yes, external to Pycharm. I mean, it works when I use system shell, the normal terminal in Linux. No remote system involved. I'm on my local machine only.

@nocomment lexists return the same of exists. Sometimes true, sometimes false. The behaviour is pretty random. I've been randomly trying with files from the same folder. The files are all there, but about 80% of the times the "exists" call returns False. see https://pastebin.com/NhzQ5RgW

Do they return False exactly for the files that are links?

@nocomment it returns False also on "non-link files". In the pastebin I pasted some examples. It also shows this behavior in the screenshots here above.

I would go as far as launching a standard shell using os.system (e.g. os.system('bash')) from that Python interactive prompt and use the standard tools (i.e. ls) to see what the process is actually seeing.

Ah yes I misread the screenshot and didn't see the pastebin (maybe that was edited in). I suggest you include that data (not just the link) at the bottom of the question.

@metatoaster it gets weirder the more I try. I counted files using "ls /absolute_path/* | wc -l" and I get 4334 items in the "external" system shell, but only 2791 in the "os.system('bash')" inside pycharm. And if I try to be more specific, if I do "ls ..path/libexp*" I get different results in the two shells (8 results in system shell and 3 using your suggestion: 2 links + 1 file). It's like python doesn't see them at all.

Right, looks like it's definitely flatpak being the root cause since you did mention this in the question. Just don't use anything flatpak since it causes more problems than it solves.

Thanks to @metatoaster for suggesting the right answer!! Apparently the issue is related to flatpak.
I solved the issue by uninstalling Pycharm from flatpak, then downloading the .tar.gz from Jetbrains website and "installing" that one (actually just unpacking).
